# Regex unicode replacing spaces and Tabulators

Tags: regex, unicode, expresso

I'm having trouble getting this regex replacement code to work "again"

I believe this used to work in /net but it never worked in Expresso ( - meaning it might never actually worked properly)[Expresson Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0yAf.jpg)

I have text string
I need to remove any spaces or Tabulators between the [;] and the [G30] - but not the line feeds!

```
N10 ;  G30
```

after the replacement --the result should be

```
N10 ;G30
```

Here is what I came up with back in the days

```
;\u0020*\u0009*(?:\w+\n)
```

If found, this should be replaced by a simple `;`

I attached the Expresso screenshot as it might make things easier to understand

Any ideas on how to make this work ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a line terminator (`\n`) after `G30`? Could it be that the whitespaces between `;` is something like `<space><tab><space>` (which doesn't match `\u0020*\u0009*`)? For the former, remove the `\n`. For the latter, use `[\u0020\u0009]*` for any sequences of such characters, in any order.

Comment: Good point with the line feed - I removed it

Comment: It kind does work  with single or multiple tabulator(s) - but the space removal does not work u0020

Comment: \;\u0020*(?:\w+)|;\u0009*(?:\w+)

Comment: Why is u0020 not working for the simple spaces? (spacebar)

Comment: Try replacing `;[\u0020\u0009]*(\w+)` with `;$1`. Oh, and... the line terminator sequence on Windows is CRLF, so instead of `\n` you have to use `\r\n`...

Comment: \;\u0020*(?:\w+\d+)|\;\u0009*(?:\w+\d+) is what I'm using "now" -this works for tabulators but not for spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question but if the goal is to remove whitespace before or after the `;` could you do:

```
[\u0020\u0009]*;[\u0020\u0009]*
```

I'm not sure about the newline issue, but perhaps there is a feature in the Expresso program on how to handle start-of-line or text (normally this is something like `^...$` or `/A.../z`).

If you want the excel `A1` formats per line then maybe something like the following would work:

- [`^([A-Z]+\d+)[\u0020*\u0009]*;[\u0020*\u0009]*([A-Z]+\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/zc6vL7/1)

[image]

Note in the above I am using the 'anchors' of `^` and `$`.

Comment: This is actually what I ened up with \;[\u0020\u0009]*(?=\w\d+\n?)

Comment: It seems to do what I need at this point "N10 ;     G30 xxxxx"  will result into "N10   ;G30 xxxx" regardless of spaces or tabulators used between the semicolon and the G30  &  it works in both Expresso and .net :-) Thanks for you're all you're inputs

Answer (score 0):

Match horizontal whitespace:

```
;\h*(?:\w+\n)
```

Or if that isn't supported for you, use a *subtraction* to match whitespace *except* new lines:

```
;[\s&&[^\n\r]]*(?:\w+\n)
```

Comment: .NET doesn't support character class operations.

Comment: Does not work within Expresso (i just like to use it for testing) - that does not necessarily mean it's not going to work within .net -It's another interesting approach -let me see if I can work it out

Answer (score 0):

If there should be at least a single word character following and you are using C#, you might use:

```
;[\p{Zs}\t]+(?=[^\W\d]+\d)
```

- `;` Match literally
- `[\p{Zs}\t]+` Match 1+ whitespace characters or tabs
- `(?=[^\W\d]+\d)` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ word chars without a digit and then a digit

In the replacement use `;`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/75qPnc/1).

If there should be a newline following after the word characters:

```
;[\p{Zs}\t]+(?=[^\W\d]+\d\w*\r?\n)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lz5PnE/1).